# how to show another dropdown box depend on dropdown box value

Tags: php

please i need help

i need to do specail command 
when some value selected then show another dropdown box 
my first dropdown box is in php 
and he is my code :

```
 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root",
    "", "phoneunlock" )
    or die("Cannot connect to database:" . 
    mysqli_connect_error($conn));
    echo "<select name='selectedValue' class= 'dropdown' >";
    echo '<option value="">'.'Please Select Service'.'</option>';
    $sql = "SELECT id, manufacter FROM product";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {       echo "<option value='" . $row['manufacter']. "'>" . $row['manufacter'] . '</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
```

and know i need some command like this : 
if dropdown box selected = value then 
do this 
end if 
sow please can any one help me

Answer (score 0):

if you mean like chained combobox. try using jQuery like this :

```js
$('#yourcomboid').on('change', function() {
  var id = $(this).val();
  $('#youranothercombo').empty();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'your-route-to-get-data/' + id,
    success: function(data) {
      $('#youranothercombo').empty();
      for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var item = data[i];
          $('#youranothercombo').append($('<option></option>').val(item.column-name).text(item.column-name));
      }
    }
   });
});
```

Hope this code works.

Comment: please i need php code because seconde combo box need to get information from database and also i will create another combo box depend on value of second combo box

Comment: you can use my method using jQuery. please try it first. or if you didn't know what you have to do, you can use the jQuery chained. Here's the link http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained

Comment: i will try it and post the result thank you for your help